# hash function for a string python syntax error

Tags: python, string, hash

I am trying to compute the hash function for a string and I am receiving a syntax error about how to convert a character at position x to an integer value. Anyone know how to correctly do this?

```
def hashFunction(inputString, r, m):

    for x in range(0,len(inputString)-1):
        hashValue = (hashValue*r+(ord)inputString[x])% m 
    return hashValue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues, first of all, you're not calling ord on an argument. You probably want this:

```
    hashValue = (hashValue*r+ord(inputString[x]))% m
```

Notice how I wrapped the argument in parentheses instead of around the function name.

The second thing is that you're using the value of hashValue when it hasn't been assigned to yet. This will give you an error when you call the function.